# How to scraping multiple table but same url in python

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium-webdriver, request

I want to get all 5 pages of data from this website http://www.witcorp.co.th/product_chem.php?txtType=1#nogo

But the problem is I can get only the first pages data table when scraping following the picture
[Chemical data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRmuJ.png)

And I try to switch to the other pages by Selenium before scrapping but seems not effective

I wrote the code following this

```py
import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'http://www.witcorp.co.th/th/product_chem.php?txtType=1#nogo'
driver.get(url)

page_html = driver.page_source
data = soup(page_html,'html.parser')

all_product = data.find_all('div',{'class':'table'})

page_4 = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="showChemicalPage"]/ul/li[5]')
page_4.click()
all_product_page4 = data.find_all('div',{'id':'showChemicalAll'})
all_product_page4
```

and the result as I told is only from the first page

Can anyone give me a hand to solve this problem, many thanks for your time in advance

Comment: I don't see any code attempts to traverse to Page 2, Page 3 or Page 4. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank for your comment ,sir , Finally I have found fot the method, only checked by (ctrl+shift+i) to get the url and then do the loop